# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have an asp.net hosted in IIS. that uses the Com library "Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library". I am using this to convert the word Document to HTML, on my machine it works. I have Office 2007 on my machine. but when i try to run my app on the server it gives me the Following error

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   E_ACCESSDENIED)).

i have given all the permissions to the aspnet user and other users full access but this does not work,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. From the Start menu, click Run and type Dcomcnfg.exe.
2. In Component Services, click Console root, expand Component Services, expand Computers, expand My computer,expand DCOMConfig.
3. Search for Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library. Click on it.
4. Right click and select Properties.
5. On security tab, select Customize in "Launch and Activation" section.
6. Click edit and add identity of app pool under which you application is running.
7. Repeat above step for "Access Permission"

Comment: For more information, If you have setting identity impersonate in web.config, you also need to add that user into dcomcnfg too.

Comment: had to activate Allow "Remote Access" despite starting and surfing IIS website locally. why?
2nd: why are there all Launch checks neccessary? didn't get it working without..