# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {...} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, interop, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-msoffice-pdf to convert a word to a pdf. This solution works perfectly on my computer.

I updated my app in IIS and I get this error when calling the web service that converts the docx to pdf:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

I have tried several answers and tutorials step by step such as:

- [Accessing Office Word object model through asp.net results in "failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477086/accessing-office-word-object-model-through-asp-net-results-in-failed-due-to-the)
- [Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937375/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-failed-due-to-the-foll)
- https://jayeshsidhwani.wordpress.com/tag/hresult-0x80070005-e_accessdenied/
- https://waheedrous.wordpress.com/2014/01/26/error-office-interop-assemblies

But I got to nowhere.

I also tried to run my app in the server but as localhost and it worked perfectly, zero problems.

I noticed that the CLSID in the error message it isn't the same as the Microsoft Word 97 - 2003 Document Component Service App ID.

The only tutorial that got me somewhere is this one http://toastergremlin.com/?p=543. The error was gone but the Word wasn't being opened and the web service just got stuck.

In the Microsoft Word 97 - 2003 Document Component Service I tried to add the following users: NETWORK_SERVICE, IIS_IUSRS, PC\Users and the apppool associated with my website.

Comment: Not directly related to your permission problem, but using interop with Office COM objects from a web server can be very error-prone.

Comment: @EricJ. I guess I'm starting to experience that :)

Comment: You should be able to determine the dll it is try to load in the registry. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}

Comment: @user957902 I get this: http://image.prntscr.com/image/9b849310b651468eb892e662ea4c2c04.png

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when trying to create my own Interop DLL thru IIS web. And after lot of searches, this post [solved](http://toastergremlin.com/?p=543) my life

Comment: The link is dead. This is why you should always include at least a partial solution in your answer and lead to a link for the details